# How do I successfully add Topic to Django admin? Using settings.py to add learning_logs to INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: python, django, localhost

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

I was directed to enter code 'learning_logs' along with installed apps and I was unable to migrate learning_logs as admin topic. I tried to edit code over again and format it as there are 2 files: learning log and learning log(s) and when I re-opened editor the edit wasn't saved and admin wasn't showing Topics to add on localhost website. Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand you correctly.

> was directed to enter code 'learning_logs' along with installed apps
> and I was unable to migrate learning_logs as admin topic

When you create a new app you have to add it to installed apps.

For example your app is named *random_app*, you can add it to **settings.py** like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',

#MY APPS
'random_app'
]
```

> and when I reopened editor the edit wasnt saved and admin wasnt
> showing Topics to add on localhost website.

Say you have a model in your app you wish to show/edit in admin panel.

For example **project/random_app/models.py** might look like this:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Go to **project/random_app/admin.py** and create your ModelAdmin:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from project.random_app.models import Topic

class TopicAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
admin.site.register(Topic, TopicAdmin)
```

Now when you log into admin, you can see **Topic** and edit/delete/insert new instances via admin.

Answer (score 0):

jackygab, thanks for swift response. The module traceback had to be edited to create 0001_initial.py. Before I asked the question, 0001_initial.py was created but not migrated. Your answer was clear and I had to use same thinking cap to understand the most difficult are actually simple challenges as a beginner.
#You da man.